# Recursive function to restructure array that inside an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recursive-datastructures

I'm currently working on displaying tables.

But im stuck because the data structure is super nested. This is the original structure:

```
   {
      "key": "parent_table",
      "title": "parent_table",
      "type": "table",
      "children": [
        {
          "key": "parent_record[0]",
          "title": "parent_record[0]",
          "children": [
            {
              "key": "parent_field_1",
              "title": "parent_field_1",
              "type": "input",
              "children": [
                {
                  "key": "parent_field_1_value",
                  "title": "parent_field_1_value",
                  "value": "2122",
                  "type": "input"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "key": "parent_field_2",
              "title": "parent_field_2",
              "type": "table",
              "children": [
                {
                  "key": "children_1_table",
                  "title": "tablerow[1]",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "key": "column1",
                      "title": "column1",
                      "type": "input",
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "key": "column1_value",
                          "title": "column1_value",
                          "value": "column1_value",
                          "type": "input"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "column2",
                      "title": "column2",
                      "type": "input",
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "key": "column2_value",
                          "title": "column2_value",
                          "value": "column2_value",
                          "type": "input"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "key": "parent_record[1]",
          "title": "parent_record[1]",
          "children": [
            {
              "key": "parent_field_1",
              "title": "parent_field_1",
              "type": "input",
              "children": [
                {
                  "key": "parent_field_1_value",
                  "title": "parent_field_1_value",
                  "value": "2122",
                  "type": "input"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "key": "parent_field_2",
              "title": "parent_field_2",
              "type": "table",
              "children": [
                {
                  "key": "children_2_table",
                  "title": "tablerow[1]",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "key": "column1",
                      "title": "column1",
                      "type": "input",
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "key": "column1_value",
                          "title": "column1_value",
                          "value": "column1_value",
                          "type": "input"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "column2",
                      "title": "column2",
                      "type": "input",
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "key": "column2_value",
                          "title": "column2_value",
                          "value": "column2_value",
                          "type": "input"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

And this is the expected data structure:

```
[
  {
    "key": "parent_table",
    "title": "parent_table",
    "type": "table",
    "children": [
      {
        "key": "parent_record[0]",
        "title": "parent_record[0]",
        "children": [
          {
            "key": "parent_field_1",
            "title": "parent_field_1",
            "type": "input",
            "children": [
              {
                "key": "parent_field_1_value",
                "title": "parent_field_1_value",
                "value": "2122",
                "type": "input"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "parent_record[1]",
        "title": "parent_record[1]",
        "children": [
          {
            "key": "parent_field_1",
            "title": "parent_field_1",
            "type": "input",
            "children": [
              {
                "key": "parent_field_1_value",
                "title": "parent_field_1_value",
                "value": "2122",
                "type": "input"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "parent_field_2",
    "title": "parent_field_2",
    "type": "table",
    "children": [
      {
        "key": "children_1_table",
        "title": "tablerow[1]",
        "children": [
          {
            "key": "column1",
            "title": "column1",
            "type": "input",
            "children": [
              {
                "key": "column1_value",
                "title": "column1_value",
                "value": "column1_value",
                "type": "input"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "key": "column2",
            "title": "column2",
            "type": "input",
            "children": [
              {
                "key": "column2_value",
                "title": "column2_value",
                "value": "column2_value",
                "type": "input"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "parent_field_2",
    "title": "parent_field_2",
    "type": "table",
    "children": [
      {
        "key": "children_2_table",
        "title": "tablerow[1]",
        "children": [
          {
            "key": "column1",
            "title": "column1",
            "type": "input",
            "children": [
              {
                "key": "column1_value",
                "title": "column1_value",
                "value": "column1_value",
                "type": "input"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "key": "column2",
            "title": "column2",
            "type": "input",
            "children": [
              {
                "key": "column2_value",
                "title": "column2_value",
                "value": "column2_value",
                "type": "input"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Basically the recursive function will pull the children table out from the parent and make the children table same layer with parent table.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WzGXQw) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hi @jcalz, YES i think this is what im actually looking for! But im still trying to apply it to my code and check whether its working in reactjs side or not. Thank you So much <3

Comment: "But im still trying to apply it to my code and check whether its working in reactjs side or not. " <-- does this mean I should wait until you figure it out?

Comment: @jcalz yes im still trying to convert it to reactjs so that can test :( but thank you for helping me. I will let you know once I done testing

Comment: @jcalz YES ITS ACTUALLY WORKING PERFECTLY FINE.  Might need your help to explain to me <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of use in TypeScript, let's define the recursive `Tree` type as follows:

```
interface Tree {
  key: string;
  title: string;
  value?: string;
  type?: string;
  children?: Tree[]
}
```

And you want to write a function with the following call signature:

```
declare function extractTables(tree: Tree): Tree[]
```

so it takes in a single `Tree`, and produce an array of `Tree`s corresponding to all the `"table"`-type tree elements from somewhere in the tree.  I assume you don't want to actually *mutate* the input tree, so we have to make copies of things before we change anything.

---

The general approach here is: we will walk recursively through the tree doing two things: producing a modified version of the current tree node suitable for appearing in the output, and collecting all the modified table tree nodes from the current subtree. At the end we only need that set of modified table tree nodes, so we will wrap the tree walker with a function that throws away the "current" node at the end.

It looks like this:

```
function extractTables(tree: Tree) {
  interface WalkResult {
    tables: Tree[],
    modified: Tree
  }
  function walk(tree: Tree): WalkResult {
    const { children, ...base } = tree;
    const tables: Tree[] = [];
    let modifiedChildren: Tree[] | undefined;
    if (children) {
      const walkedChildren = children.map(walk);
      modifiedChildren = walkedChildren
        .filter(wr => wr.modified.type !== "table")
        .map(wr => wr.modified);
      walkedChildren
        .forEach(wr => tables.push(...wr.tables));
    }
    const modified = { ...base, ...children && { children: modifiedChildren } };
    if (modified.type === "table") tables.unshift(modified);
    return { tables, modified };
  }
  return walk(tree).tables;
}
```

So the inner `walk()` function is recursive and returns a `WalkResult`, and `extractTables()` returns the `tables` property of `walk(tree)`.

The `walk()` function itself must take the current node and the `WalkResult`s from running `walk` on all its `children` (if they exist), and produce a `WalkResult` for the current node.

It starts by splitting the current node into its `children` property and everything else (using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)).

If the current node has `children`, then we recursively `walk` each child.  The current modified node needs a modified `children`, which we form by collecting each non-`"table"` modified child.  And every set of `tables` encountered in the `children` should be concatenated together and used for the `tables` we return (if there are no `children`, then this list of tables is empty).

We build up the current modified node by adding back together the non-`children` properties and the modified `children` (if it exists).  If the current node is a `table` then we need to prepend it to the list of tables we've built up from the children. And now we have a current modified node and a current list of modified table nodes, so we can return our `WalkResult`.

So that's it, we're done.

---

We can check that `extractTables(input)` for your example input produces the same structure as your example output:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(output) === JSON.stringify(expectedOutput)); // true
```

And it does!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpQig3gWAFDLIDWEAngFzIDOYUoA5gNz6FjBgA2ElNdITLZADc4HAK4QA-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-CBqVG1C9f2PPMQHfcxamxW4TzId9PxvW8MGWKB9HMAAGSxHwtD82E4ICPyvRDkPtNDMOw8NFjVMCIJwwhoJxf9T3gojv1vf4DFvABGCjGJgvC3wvVjwHY1pOJ4v8+P-Wt4J3MQwF4qSPxoyhIMoqSGKUj9mKEr8RI4-RuNvERxG1SStOk18CIQtiDKMkyJEUiyPwc6yACYuLctynIsgDVFkkBdzVOicUjJTrHUxYbHMnFNJxWCz10xC7O8mLGJffCWL0u8Up89KZOAp48vilT3hC244qkhL4LAoyQMiqqBOsxsoDcAZzC4rC0qU6ibW2WiGqUyrfJ05S3HEOoQAk8qeqamrxrESbpsGrS-OsuSFO65zet5cDVJmrThucpi4IvZYJqm4zREcrbjsszKzoWpartM4q7v-Vz5ouriXpug7fIKj8NuClaLLC97kAiiHov+irYfi0bqKekBUvh-irK+xaUbegHAICoLbtW0q1IhuHQe2xHzqxtzfrMtG+IywSxoumnPsJ461U+x6WdpnG7rW-H5JB0movpwgofe8GLIlrSpcYmXQpwhWYcouLqqStiSNQjqupwxnrOEu8tbQzrip2ksBo0mb1cI7LRIgcS+dwjGNf0sTDOW1bAbVYH2fNklLYso6EdO23kvd+zrrp8mqLm12cojn62fhzmo-gjyvKd-i8YvYH-rlnEFduFWrdBm2bLdh3DNRsu47D2yI5rr2c9woq-eJ-7g5gym+pAW8afq-m641J5Wva032ZgjuY7JkXy6ppas4Z4eF6mpf8pbn3AqFyeGenkX6LFkPEuZrGk7T3evZd0-nuTmeeq5m-Lrvg-Y83vP78YgvnKLsHL8WLuDNKbIybqTfWmNJqgIhgLXO29NpH39kYQOItAGrWATzF+r9nYPSfqzC+R8YKPyRhg-Bn9l7vzgcLA+39pb0xofLfOM1f4RiVrUMKEVpx4C3EUHwqhXBtAAPLyV3GCN4JNiiUXLobe8bdajgPjjIrUPkYGtyUTFRB-V9qRWGlIu2xsMK60GvI+uIl9HkVuhovaZVQaAN0eHKu3El7GIrgnBxntcb+VgQTf6ljkFB3pnYhubjeb-3ukzFx9txIhICUQjOUCObew-ndehixmGi0Gr-EusUQqBNMRAFCJtDGNWvhE-RE8cn7yGj4xG0i7LuKvjgiJdSnGJMobvXxWi7qoKojUu2dTolkOcbUxOAzoGxM8vE7arSgrwxSeLGaNDMm1AllkhiuTXGcXiUMvpjdlHe0HlRSps8gGh0sXVWRRjh4tTajrHGHTrGHWqac1e9TZolJeS0ih3iY73PEc5bpJ0T7ELPqM96ziXmgv5kQiFmCh5fKFrM-6aSIzs1seg6mLT3kgM+Z4oGbSfFHP8YM9FkDIUJKxSQ16oSXJp25tTMlUz4UKURTHZFU4QpLMoisySazen2M2XskpwyHFbP2Rcqevc-GHyMT3Xa-dFFvgsVc0eNzylGMJYxNFzzkavOKY0j57Tpk7wJZKzpx0AXaW1d9BlAMKUgthRzaFOqbXN1xVvGZ985mQwWaip5QLV6TOXnayBOL1r4p+RqqpxKrX0odVM4NKMXUP1pbgpNjUmVUOcl6tliycJSxWfgSw8hNz3GQG4YR8k3g+D8K4QIq4wgbRiOMYteAAD0rbkAojALoKgZaK1gF7bQCQXghDQFIN2hgnbe1uCIHAUgJa8TjQgHsDgbh6BhAAFIAGUBEADk9i8AYM0UgYRy1gF3PEesyBt17oPbIfgx6wi8PyZAfQQjz3yVDEAA)